# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, data-science

so here is my code, I'm using OpenCV's cascade files to detect face and eye position and then using it in the following part.

```
# Importing relevant libraries

import cv2 import os import tensorflow from keras.models import load_model import numpy as np import pygame import time

# Adding alarm to raise alert pygame.init() sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('alarm.wav')

# initialising -> cascade files into cascade classifier -> OpenCV

face = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/ankush/Desktop/sleepy-driver-alert/haar-cascade-files/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml') l_eye = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/ankush/Desktop/sleepy-driver-alert/haar-cascade-files/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml') r_eye = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/ankush/Desktop/sleepy-driver-alert/haar-cascade-files/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml')

# start-of-execution label = ['Close', 'Open']

# load model and video capture

model = load_model('/Users/ankush/Desktop/sleepy-driver-alert/models/cnnCat2.h5') path = os.getcwd() cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL count = 0 score = 0 dep = 2 rpred = [99] lpred = [99]

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width = frame.shape[:2]

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face.detectMultiScale(gray, minNeighbors=5, scaleFactor=1.1, minSize=(25, 25))
    left_eye_gray = r_eye.detectMultiScale(gray)
    right_eye_gray = l_eye.detectMultiScale(gray)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, height - 50), (200, height),
                  (0, 0, 0), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (100, 100, 100), 1)

    # Next few lines check if eyes are open or not ->rpred,lpred variables

    # right

    for (x, y, w, h) in right_eye_gray:
        r_eye = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        count = count + 1
        r_eye = cv2.cvtColor(r_eye, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        r_eye = cv2.resize(r_eye, (24, 24))
        r_eye = r_eye / 255
        r_eye = r_eye.reshape(24, 24, -1)
        r_eye = np.expand_dims(r_eye, axis=0)
        rpred = model.predict_classes(r_eye)
        if (rpred[0] == 1):
            label = 'Open'
        if (rpred[0] == 0):
            label = 'Closed'
        break

    # left

    for (x, y, w, h) in left_eye_gray:
        l_eye = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        count = count + 1
        l_eye = cv2.cvtColor(l_eye, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        l_eye = cv2.resize(l_eye, (24, 24))
        l_eye = l_eye / 255
        l_eye = l_eye.reshape(24, 24, -1)
        l_eye = np.expand_dims(l_eye, axis=0)
        lpred = model.predict_classes(l_eye)
        if (lpred[0] == 1):
            label = 'Open'
        if (lpred[0] == 0):
            label = 'Closed'
        break

    # if closed eyes detected

    if (rpred[0] == 0 and lpred[0] == 0):
        score = score + 1
        cv2.putText(frame, "Closed", (10, height - 20), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    # if for some reason only one is closed, driver is not sleeping
    else:
        score = score - 1
        cv2.putText(frame, "Open", (10, height - 20), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    if (score < 0):
        score = 0
        cv2.putText(frame, 'Score:' + str(score), (100, height - 20), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # if person is very sleepy, high score, eyes closed

    if (score > 15):

        cv2.imwrites(os.path.join(path, 'image.jpg'), frame)
        try:
            sound.play()
        except:
            pass

    if (dep < 16):
        dep = dep + 2

    else:
        dep = dep - 2
        if (dep < 2):
            dep = 2
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, 0), (width, height), (0, 0, 255), dep)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the error that I'm getting is;

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/ankush/Desktop/sleepy-driver-alert/Sleepy-driver-detector.py",
>   line 44, in 
>       right_eye_gray = l_eye.detectMultiScale(gray) AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale'

What am I doing wrong? I'm a beginner.

Comment: The error says it, `right_eye_gray = l_eye.detectMultiScale(gray)` is not valid since in this case `l_eye` is a numpy array, not a `cv2.CasscadeClassifier` instance.

Comment: What kind of object has this `detect...` method?  Clearly numpy array does not.

Comment: I think this will help you [Parameters of detectMultiScale in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218385/parameters-of-detectmultiscale-in-opencv-using-python)